# Error when upload file - laravel 5

Tags: laravel

Controller:

```
public function store(StoreSongRequest $request)
{
    dd($request->get('song'));die;
}
```

create.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'songs.store', 'class' => 'form', 'novalidate' => 'novalidate', 'files' => true)) !!}

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Name') !!}
     {!! Form::text('name') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Upload') !!}
    {!! Form::file('song') !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Upload', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) !!}
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When i submit i appear error:

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:

I was comment out 'app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken' in kernel.php file but still the same.

Comment: My problem was resolved!. I was set post_max_size in php.ini

Comment: Then either post your own answer or delete the question

Comment: @TriMinh if you solve your problem, post your solution to your own question. this may help further readers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `post_max_size` was low $_POST. Increasing `post_max_size` in php.ini solved the issue.